# Where's the Edit Toolbar Button in Preview Application

Tags: preview, image-editing

I can't find the Edit Button to toggle the Edit Toolbar in the Preview Application

Here's a screencap of a file that's open in editor:

[image]

On the support page [Mac Basics: Preview app views and edits images and PDFs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201740), there's an edit button like in the following picture:

[image]

However, I don't see that option anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that was just an outdated version of preview.  In the new version the button is called [**Markup**](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20227?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) and is in the same location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my copy of preview, if I go to the View menu and select "Customize Toolbar..." I have a list of all commands that can be added to the toolbar. Just drag them from the sheet sheet that slides down to the tool bar and you are good to go.